# Why Hall effect sensor has only three pins?

Tags: sensor, hall-effect

Hall effect sensors have three terminals (pins). Why not four?

[image]
[image]([source](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/electromagnetism/hall-effect.html))

Comment: Look at the diagram of a typical switch and you will see what they are for. Then try to remove any of them and look of it would still work

Comment: @PlasmaHH question updated.

Comment: I think people here are looking for more explanation in your question....like why do you expect it to have four pins and so on...

Comment: As shown in your drawing, the Hall sensor itself, buried inside the switch package, does have four terminals.  However, the surrounding circuit only needs three terminals to connect to the outside world - power, ground, and output.

Comment: The standard answer "Because it can" applies. 4 leads would be possible but there may be materials and bias issues due to the common silicon substrate (which is why most MOSFETs have an "intrinsic" body diode), 3 leads works acceptably well and allows small transistor packages t be used (TO92, SOT23, ...) and one less lead allows (very slightly) lower cost.

Comment: The Hall sensor does have 4 (internally).  But none of them are brought out.  Which equals 0 actually.  Anyway your schematic is for a Hall Effect Switch.

Comment: Like... Why should it? It does it's job with three.

Comment: I think you confusing apples and oranges. What your showing is only a switch to indicate the presence of a magnetic field beyond a certain strength. A Hall Effect sensor designed to indicate strength and polarity may have 4 pins. With 4 pins you could have a differential output and a bipolar supply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typical packaged hall effect sensing device includes extra circuitry to convert the tiny hall effect differential voltage into something easier to use.

In the second image you show above, you can see the raw hall effect sensor depicted as a an orange box with an "X" in it. It does, in fact, have 4 connections and exactly matches the connections of the hall effect sensor shown in your top image if you take that top one and flip and rotate it.

The hall voltage in the sensor is feed into a differential amplifier shown as a triangle with an "A" in it. This takes the very very tiny hall voltage and amplifies to a much stronger signal. This is then compared to a threshold and that is used to turn the output transistor on or off. The output transistor generates the single signal a the hall effect switch output pin.

Answer (score 1):

Why should it have 4 terminals ?

Look, your sensor just indicating either there is an hall effect or not.

For a IC to be a part of any circuit, it must have a common node (GND ) , and all the voltages are measured with respect to this point as by voltage we means voltage difference between two nodes. So there is a pin for GND.

Then you need to provide higher voltage to run the IC and voltage to create hall effect. as you already have GND , you just need another pin for supply voltage. here goes your second pin.

Now it's time to see the result. You will find high voltage if hall effect exist and no voltage if there is none. So your output will be shown in voltage . As you already measuring all the voltages with respect to GND , you only need one more pin so that you can see voltage difference between that pin and GND. here goes your third pin OUTPUT.

Or in one line I can say that , the 4 terminal you are considering from the hall effect diagram; the GND pin alone do the part of 2 pins.

That's why there is 3 pin ,not 4.